# DataMatrix-encoding with zxing only generates 14px bitmap

Tags: android, barcode, zxing, datamatrix

I'm using zxing to generate barcodes with different types (EAN, 2of5 and DataMatrix). Generating in general works fine. The only problem I currently have is that zxing only generates a 14x14 pixel bitmap which is way too small. But only when using DataMatrix! EAN13, 2of5/ITF and QR-Codes work perfect with the same code.

My code:

```
BitMatrix bitMatrix = new DataMatrixWriter().encode(message, BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX, 1080, 1080, null);
int height = bitMatrix.getHeight(); //height is always 14, it doesn't matter what value I pass to the encoder
```

As you can imagine this looks pretty shitty on a 1080p screen like the nexus 5. Am I getting something wrong? Do I have to do some special settings for DataMatrix?

Google and Stackoverflow couldn't help me so far as I can't find any examples for the usage of DataMatrix

[image: App screenshot of DataMatrix barcode]

**Update**
This is how I convert the bitmatrix to a bitmap

```
    int width = bitMatrix.getWidth();
    int height = bitMatrix.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    // All are 0, or black, by default
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        int offset = y * width;
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            pixels[offset + x] = bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
        }
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
```

If I use any other values for the height I get an OutOfBoundsException which is pretty obvious (I didn't expect anything else)...

When I try to scale the imageview and set a fixed width and height, the barcode is scannable but looks like shit. This is obvious too, as the bitmatrix is only 14x14 instead of the size I specified.

[image]

Is there a simple way to somehow scale a bitmatrix? Because it only consists of dots so it should be possible but I don't want to calculate it myself. I couldn't find any documentation for bitmatrix besides stackoverflow and this didn't help me at all.

If I pass a MinWidth or MaxWidth to the encoder via HintMap the app always crashes with an Exception.
HintMap (mWidth is the display width of the device but I tried several values):
    Hashtable hintMap
                        = new Hashtable();

```
hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.MIN_SIZE, new Dimension(mWidth, mWidth));
hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.MAX_SIZE, new Dimension(mWidth, mWidth));
hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.DATA_MATRIX_SHAPE, SymbolShapeHint.FORCE_SQUARE);
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find a symbol arrangement that matches the message. Data codewords: 7
```

This last issue seems to me like a bug in zxing. I don't get it why the generating doesn't work if I change the size.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a small example how you can change your method for the conversion from BitMatrix to Bitmap. The method does the scaling of the BitMatrix.

```
int BLACK = 0xFF000000;
int WHITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;

// change the values to your needs
int requestedWidth = 300;
int requestedHeight = 300;

int width = bitMatrix.getWidth();
int height = bitMatrix.getHeight();

// calculating the scaling factor
int pixelsize = requestedWidth/width;
if (pixelsize > requestedHeight/height)
{
  pixelsize = requestedHeight/height;
}

int[] pixels = new int[requestedWidth * requestedHeight];
// All are 0, or black, by default
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
  int offset = y * requestedWidth * pixelsize;

  // scaling pixel height
  for (int pixelsizeHeight = 0; pixelsizeHeight < pixelsize; pixelsizeHeight++, offset+=requestedWidth) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      int color = bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;

      // scaling pixel width
      for (int pixelsizeWidth = 0; pixelsizeWidth < pixelsize; pixelsizeWidth++) {
        pixels[offset + x * pixelsize + pixelsizeWidth] = color;
      }
    }
  }
}
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(requestedWidth, requestedHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, requestedWidth, 0, 0, requestedWidth, requestedHeight);

// I could only test it with BufferedImage and a modified version of the zxing J2SE client
// BufferedImage bitmap = new BufferedImage(requestedWidth, requestedHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
// bitmap.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, requestedWidth, requestedHeight, pixels);
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed! Calculating the scale and creating the bitmap just in the resultion I need.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you very much. No matter what you do the library always returns a really small datamatrix so the only solution is to scale it.

Answer (score 4):

As I remember, the Data Matrix encoder is kind of the odd man out since the code came from a different place (barcode4j). It will use the minimum appropriate dimensions and assumes the caller will scale the graphic as desired.

You can do that here -- just set the `ImageView` to scale its contents. That shouldn't hurt for any of the encoded barcodes, as long as you do not enable anti-aliasing.

There is also a `EncodeHintType.MIN_SIZE` hint which will set the minimum size, just for Data Matrix.

Comment: Thanks. Scaling the ImageView doesn't work as it destroys the barcode. As I said, the bitmatrix is only 14x14 pixels. I'm messing with the EncodeHintType for a long time now. When I set a min size I always get an IllegalArgumentException with the message "Can't find a symbol arrangement that matches the message. Data codewords: 1". There's no documentation what exactly this means...

Comment: How would it destroy the barcode? It is pure squares. You definitely can't use antialiasing in scaling though.

Comment: Other could be a bug. What are you encoding and exactly?

Comment: I've updated my original post to show more code. In the screenshot you can see what I'm trying to encode. But it doesn't matter what I want to encode, it doesn't work with other values.

Comment: You should only set one of the encoding hints MIN_SIZE or MAX_SIZE. In your case set only MIN_SIZE to avoid the exception. But I think  the result isn't what you expect. The encoding hint doesn't scale the BitMatrix. It leads to another symbol shape.

Comment: Yeah you are asking for a 1x1 matrix and it is not possible. I think you want to remove both of the first 2 hints.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is about Android, but I think could be classified as generic.
I'm working with Swift and the the wrapper ZXingObjC. I obtain this error using DataMatrix encoding:

> 'Can't find a symbol arrangement that matches the message. Data
>   codewords: 5'

So, debugging code, I arrived to class ZXDataMatrixSymbolInfo, on method:

```
+ (ZXDataMatrixSymbolInfo *)lookup:(int)dataCodewords shape:(ZXDataMatrixSymbolShapeHint)shape minSize:(ZXDimension *)minSize
```

When happens?

I write a custom swift wrapper (CoderEncoder) for my project, with this method:

```
static func encode(string code: String, encoding: CoderEncorderType, size: CGSize = CGSizeMake(200, 200)) -> UIImage? {
    let writer: ZXWriter = ZXMultiFormatWriter.writer() as! ZXWriter
    do {
        let format = CodeEncoder.getEncoding(type: encoding) 
        let result = try writer.encode(code, format: format, width: Int32(size.width), height: Int32(size.height))
        let cgImage = ZXImage(matrix: result, onColor: UIColor.blackColor().CGColor, offColor: UIColor.clearColor().CGColor).cgimage
        return UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        ERLog(what: error)
    }
    return nil
}
```

So, when I call:

```
CoderEncoder.encode("foo", .DataMatrix)
```

error occurs.

Basically, in ZXDataMatrixWriter maxSize is nil so you need to specify a dimension from 10 to 144.

[image]

or!! or specify the shape:

> ZXDataMatrixSymbolShapeHintForceSquare
>   ZXDataMatrixSymbolShapeHintForceRectangle

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a simple way to somehow scale a bitmatrix?

Yes, there is. Problem is that using Android automatic scaling hits some problems:

1. Android uses bi-linear filtering when scaling
2. [bi-linear filtering cannot be disabled when using Hardware Acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16308970/813810)

The approach I've taken is to scale manually by an integer factor the Bitmap. Here's how to convert a BitMatrix to an unscaled Bitmap:

```
 /**
 * Create an unscaled bitmap (1 square = 1 pixel) from a bitmatrix
 *
 * @param bitMatrix the bitmatrix to convert
 * @return a unscaled bitmap
 */
public Bitmap drawUnscaledBitmap(BitMatrix bitMatrix) {
    final int bmWidth = bitMatrix.getWidth();
    final int bmHeight = bitMatrix.getHeight();
    final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmWidth, bmHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    int[] pixels = new int[bmWidth * bmHeight];
    for (int y = 0; y < bmHeight; y++) {
        int offset = y * bmWidth;
        for (int x = 0; x < bmWidth; x++) {
            pixels[offset + x] = bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE;
        }
    }
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, bmWidth, 0, 0, bmWidth, bmHeight);
    return bitmap;
}
```

and here's how to scale up a Bitmap to (almost) fit a desired rectangle size:

```
/**
 * Upscale a bitmap (maintaining ratio) by the biggest integer scaling factor that allows the bitmap to still fit in the given size
 *
 * @param bitmap the bitmap to upscale
 * @param size   the size that the output scaled bitmap needs to fit in
 * @return the scaled bitmap if the integer scaling factor is > 1; the original bitmap otherwise
 */
public Bitmap drawScaledBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Size size) {
    final int bmWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    final int bmHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
    final int wScalingFactor = size.getWidth() / bmWidth;
    final int hScalingFactor = size.getHeight() / bmHeight;
    final int scalingFactor = Math.min(wScalingFactor, hScalingFactor);
    return scalingFactor > 1 ? Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bmWidth * scalingFactor, bmHeight * scalingFactor, false) : bitmap;
}
```